# Transferring game progress from Iphone 4 to Iphone 6

Tags: iphone

I recently purchased a new iphone 6.  I went to the cloud and reloaded my apps from my old iphone 4 however all of my progress has been lost.  Can somebody please explain how I can recover that information.  I have backed up my 4 to the cloud and then backed up the 6 but still no luck.  I am not very computer savvy so any support would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Brink39

Comment: most online games keep your progress ect...on they server. Once you log in it validates it against your ID and the device? so you might be out of luck :(

Comment: But I found this and you can try it http://www.imobie.com/support/transfer-app-games-from-iphone-to-iphone.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a backup of your iPhone 4 and then RESTORE the iPhone 6 from that backup. Depending on the game you might also need to sign in to either their service in-app or to iCloud (depending on where it saves your progress).